# Get specific elements of a Map in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

For a given map like this:

```
const contacts = new Map()
contacts.set('Jessie', {phone: "213-555-1234", address: "123 N 1st Ave"})
contacts.set('Hilary', {phone: "617-555-4321", address: "321 S 2nd St"})
```

How can I get the list of "phone"s?
Something like:

```
console.log(contacts.getKey("phone"))
```

> expected answer: ["213-555-1234", "617-555-4321"]

Comment: The keys of the Map are `Jessie` and `Hilary`.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use a map keyed by name if you want to get all phone numbers, you'd have to loop over every item.

Comment: yes, but without iterating with the keys, can I get the elements?

Comment: No you would need to loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly iterate the Map object using its built-in iterator that works with a `for` loop.  This has the advantage that it doesn't make unnecessary intermediate arrays or copies of the data.  As such, it should be more efficient on larger sets of data.

```js
const contacts = new Map()
contacts.set('Jessie', {phone: "213-555-1234", address: "123 N 1st Ave"});
contacts.set('Hilary', {phone: "617-555-4321", address: "321 S 2nd St"});

let phoneNumbers = [];
for (let value of contacts.values()) {
    phoneNumbers.push(value.phone);
}
console.log(phoneNumbers);
```

Or, you could write yourself a little helper function to do this work for you, so then you can reuse the logic elsewhere:

```js
function mapGetField(map, field) {
    let results = [];
    for (let value of map.values()) {
        results.push(value[field]);
    }
    return results;
}

const contacts = new Map()
contacts.set('Jessie', {phone: "213-555-1234", address: "123 N 1st Ave"});
contacts.set('Hilary', {phone: "617-555-4321", address: "321 S 2nd St"});

console.log(mapGetField(contacts, "phone"));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the map's values with the `values()` method, then use `.map()` to extract from them.

```js
const contacts = new Map()
contacts.set('Jessie', {phone: "213-555-1234", address: "123 N 1st Ave"})
contacts.set('Hilary', {phone: "617-555-4321", address: "321 S 2nd St"})

console.log(Array.from(contacts.values()).map(c => c.phone));
```

There's nothing built-in that automatically gets properties of map elements.

Comment: Why not just iterate and build an array of phone numbers from the iterator?  `Array.from(contacts.values())` makes a whole extra copy of all the data.

Comment: @jfriend00 Because I like using the higher-order functions